# NetworkX: How to find the source and target nodes of a directed edge

Tags: python, graph, nodes, networkx, edges

dito above.. I couldn't find anything in the NetworkX docs...

In Python Igraph, i can just use:

```
import igraph as ig
G = ig.Graph(directed=True)
G.add_vertices(2)
G.add_edge(0,1)
eid = G.get_eid(0,1)
edge = G.es[eid]
nodes = (edge.source, edge.target)
print nodes
```

Comment: If you can provide a bit more information about what you want, that would make it easier to answer your question.  What is your starting point?  A directed edge?

Comment: @Joel: see edit above ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Event though I came too late I want to contribute with my proposal, since I was looking for the same answer:

I am also looking for a command in the networkx package to find the "sources" and the "targets" of a Directed graph. But "sources" and "targets" of a Directed graph within the frame of Graph Theory are not simply the sources and targets of each edge as replied in this thread, but the equivalent of leaves for an undirected Graph. That is, source and target nodes whose degree is 1 (in different direction, of course).

I'd propose the following code:

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.DiGraph()  # initializes a directed graph
edges = [(1,2),(2,3),(3,5),(4,5),(5,6)]
G.add_edges_from(edges)  # adds the edges to the graph G
sources = [x for x in G.nodes() if G.out_degree(x)==1 and G.in_degree(x)==0]
targets = [x for x in G.nodes() if G.out_degree(x)==0 and G.in_degree(x)==1]
```

Answer (score 4):

The ordering of the tuples is significant.  The first element is the source and the second is the target.

```
In [1]: import networkx as nx

In [2]: G = nx.DiGraph()

In [3]: G.add_edge(1,2) # 1->2

In [4]: G.add_edge(2,3) # 2->3

In [5]: list(G.edges())
Out[5]: [(1, 2), (2, 3)] # 1->2 and 2->3

In [6]: G.add_edge(42,17) # 42->17

In [7]: list(G.edges())
Out[7]: [(1, 2), (2, 3), (42, 17)]

In [8]: for e in G.edges():
   ...:     source,target = e
   ...:     print source
   ...:     
1
2
42
```

Answer (score 2):

For networkx edges are just tuples with two node instances:

```
g = networkx.DiGraph()
g.add_edge(1,2)
edge1 = networkx.edges(g)[0]
print type(edge1), edge1
print "source:", edge1[0]
print "target:", edge1[1]
print g.neighbors(edge1[0])
```

Comment: @sal: Then you should probably be a little bit more specific about what exactly you want to know!

Comment: this indeed answered the question. You asked how to find a list of source and target edges

Answer (score -1):

Simply use the g.edges().

```
import networkx as nx
g=nx.Graph()
```

Add your nodes and edges, the way you wish, and when you have it

```
g.edges()
```

will return a list of tuples which includes your adjacent nodes.